# Hierarchical certification authorities and CRLs

Tags: pki, certificate-authority, crl

If I implement a PKI with multiple levels of CAs, do I need to have a CRL for each individual CA or can I just have one CRL for the entire hierarchy (i.e. point all certificates to a single CRL), or only a few at the upper levels of the hierarchy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each CA will need to publish its own CRL.

The reason that it's not possible from a technical perspective to combine multiple CRLs is that each CRL needs to be cryptographically signed by the CA that generated it, so it's a 1-CA-to-1-CRL relationship.

Comment: It is quite common to publish all the CRLs to the same website, though - as long as that location is the location specified in the CDP of any issued certificates.